# Bootstrap 3 cdn glyphicons not loading in firefox only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 CDN's glyphicon is not showing up in firefox. It will show in Chrome,Safari and  Internet explorer.

I am loading boostrap cdn with the follwing:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

Below is the page with the glyphicon: (it is to the right of the grey list items)

http://www.jussbuss.tv/testing/jbresponsive

Comment: Additional note for those using this, http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/ is now the officially supported domain -- over netdna.bootstrapcdn.com.

Comment: Update 07/2017: for Bootstrap 3.3.7 go to https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2044 and https://github.com/MaxCDN/bootstrap-cdn/issues/196

It should be fixed now, try clearing your cache.