# Angularjs ui bootstrap date picker icon issue in firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-ui, angularjs-bootstrap

I am using Angularjs ui bootstrap date picker but the icon `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>` is not appearing properly in firefox but the icon is fine in Chrome. Please see the attached screen shot  for Mozilla. How can I fix it?

The following is my jsp code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled=true datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" style="height: 20px; width: 79px" ng-model="ui3DataSet.toDate" is-open="openedSecond" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openSecond($event)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</button>
```

[image: date picker icon issue]

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060994/bootstrap-3-cdn-glyphicons-not-loading-in-firefox-only

Comment: i am also having same issue.. can anyone help me? what can i do for that?

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use the tag  **span**
instead of the tag **i**. This works for me.  (I can't write comments)

Comment: But it is not working for me. When replaced with font awesome <i class="fa fa-calendar" ></i>, it is fine after date input box, but after calender pops up the left and right arrows in the calender have same problem. I am looking for the way to replace them too with font awesome.